# Google Adwords API Invalid content was found starting with element 'serviceSelector'

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-ads-api

I am trying to  retrive feeds from Google Adwords API using nodejs.I can retrieve campaigns successfully as below..

```
var selector = {
        fields: ['id','name'],
        ordering: [{field: 'name', sortOrder: 'ASCENDING'}],
        paging: {startIndex: 0, numberResults: AdwordsConstants.RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE}
      };
   campaignService.get({serviceSelector: selector}, (error, result) => {
      return res.send(result);
    });
```

but when I tried with feedService  instead of campaignService.. it is giving me below error.

```
Unmarshalling Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'serviceSelector'. One of '{\"https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201705\":selector}' is expected.
```

i have searched for answer the whole morning without success.please kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FeedItemService or FeedService, the parameter is just called `selector` instead of `serviceSelector`.

Reference: [FeedService.get()](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/FeedService#get), [FeedItemService.get()](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/FeedItemService#get)

Answer (score 0):

This one seem to work for me:

```
var campaignService = user.getService('CampaignService', 'v201609')

//create selector 
var selector = {
    fields: ['Id', 'Name'],
    ordering: [{field: 'Name', sortOrder: 'ASCENDING'}],
    paging: {startIndex: 0, numberResults: AdwordsConstants.RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE}
}

campaignService.get({serviceSelector: selector}, function (error, result) {
    console.log(error, result);
})
```

Comment: yes, it works fine. but feedItemService is not working .